# Null Object Pattern, Recursive Class, and Forward Declarations

Tags: c++, recursion, object, null, default

I'm interested in doing something like the following to adhere to a Null Object design pattern and to avoid prolific NULL tests:

```
class Node;
Node* NullNode;

class Node {
public:
  Node(Node *l=NullNode, Node *r=NullNode) : left(l), right(r) {};
private:
  Node *left, *right;
};

NullNode = new Node();
```

Of course, as written, NullNode has different memory locations before and after the Node class declaration.  You could do this without the forward declaration, if you didn't want to have default arguments (i.e., remove Node *r=NullNode).

Another option would use some inheritence:  make a parent class (Node) with two children (NullNode and FullNode).  Then the node example above would be the code for FullNode and the NullNode in the code above would be of type NullNode inheriting from Node.  I hate solving simple problems by appeals to inheritence.

So, the question is:  how do you apply Null Object patterns to recursive data structures (classes) with default arguments (which are instances of that same class!) in C++?

Comment: You still have to compare all of your nodes to `NullNode` to see if they're valid or not.  What does this save you?

Comment: Donnie,

The general idea is that instead of: if (NULL test) do nothing else do something.  You would do:  thisObject.doStuff() If thisObject is the NullObject then it (voila!) does nothing (perhaps it has many empty function definitions {}).  If thisObject is a "real node", then it does something useful (say prints itself).  Compare NullNode::Print() {} versus FullNode::Print{ cout << member1 << end;}.

Comment: Without inheritance (and making everything polymorphic), wouldn't the Node methods each have to check whether the current instance is the NullNode, so they wouldn't do anything? Another question: what about methods that *return* something? What would the NullNode return in these cases?

Comment: Looking at the wikipedia article, it doesn't appear to me that the point of the pattern is to do away with any NULL objects and/or exceptions. If a function could return an empty string to indicate "no result", there may not be much point in returning NULL instead. This doesn't mean there won't be cases where you need to distinguish between no result and error. In particular, this pattern seems unsuitable for ADT. Consider linked list: so it would be terminated with a null object? How would you then recognize the end? Right, you'll still have to test the pointer.

Comment: The point is that any "filler type" that is used to indicate "no result" that is not of the actual type we are working with, is a "bad idea".  I put bad idea in quotes, b/c that's the claim.  It's really a tradeoff.  If you expect a Node and you get NULL, "", or 0 you still have to check for it.  If you return this "thing" then you have to return a union of "no result" and "useful thing".

Using inheritance and polymorphism (btw, without inheritance: are you suggesting function overloading is sufficient?), you remove the check (if/then or try/except).

See Martin, Agile SW Develop, page 189.

Comment: In the case of returning, the point is that you may return a Node and it will be a FullNode or a NullNode.  Both of which are real, implement the right interface, and don't have to be error/empty checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `extern`:

```
extern Node* NullNode;
...
Node* NullNode = new Node();
```

Better yet, make it a static member:

```
class Node {
public:
  static Node* Null;
  Node(Node *l=Null, Node *r=Null) : left(l), right(r) {};
private:
  Node *left, *right;
};

Node* Node::Null = new Node();
```

That said, in both existing code, and amendments above, you leak an instance of `Node`. You could use `auto_ptr`, but that would be dangerous because of uncertain order of destruction of globals and statics (a destructor of some global may need `Node::Null`, and it may or may not be already gone by then).

Comment: Right.  Absolutely, I knew I was forgetting one of the "name manipulators".  I forgot about extern b/c I normally use it in a different context (i.e., a declaration external to the current file!).  I think I'm leaning towards an inheritence based solution so that the NullNode can be made to "do nothing" (as opposed to test everywhere).  This is sample code for students, so I'm balancing readability of the code (too many tests clutter things up) with readability of the class structure (inheritance may make eyes glaze over).  Thanks!

Comment: Self-correction: order of initialization is a problem regardless of whether you use `auto_ptr` or not. If you absolutely need to get it right, you'll have to use the "phoenix singleton" pattern.

Answer (score 3):

I've actually implemented a recursive tree (for JSON, etc.) doing something like this. Basically, your base class becomes the "NULL" implementation, and its interface is the union of all interfaces for the derived. You then have derived classes that implement the pieces- "DataNode" implements data getters and setters, etc.

That way, you can program to the base class interface and save yourself A LOT of pain. You set up the base implementation to do all the boilerplate logic for you, e.g.

```
class Node {
    public:
    Node() {}
    virtual ~Node() {}

    virtual string OutputAsINI() const { return ""; }
};

class DataNode {
    private:
    string myName;
    string myData;

    public:
    DataNode(const string& name, const string& val);
    ~DataNode() {}

    string OutputAsINI() const { string out = myName + " = " + myData; return out; }
};
```

This way I don't have to test anything- I just blindly call "`OutputAsINI()`". Similar logic for your whole interface will make most of the null tests go away.

Answer (score 0):

Invert the hierarchy. Put the null node at the base:

```
class Node {
public:
  Node() {}
  virtual void visit() const {}
};
```

Then specialize as needed:

```
template<typename T>
class DataNode : public Node {
public:
  DataNode(T x, const Node* l=&Null, const Node* r=&Null)
    : left(l), right(r), data(x) {}

  virtual void visit() const {
    left->visit();
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
    right->visit();
  }

private:
  const Node *left, *right;
  T data;
  static const Node Null;
};

template<typename T>
const Node DataNode<T>::Null = Node();
```

Sample usage:

```
int main()
{
  DataNode<char> a('A', new DataNode<char>('B'),
                        new DataNode<char>('C'));

  a.visit();

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./node 
B
A
C
```

Comment: I came to a similar conclusion on the drive home yesterday.  Any thoughts on cost/benefit to the Node->DataNode hierarchy versus Node->NullNode and Node->DataNode version?  What might modifications might we make that would make one more flexible than the other?

Comment: With `NullNode` as the base, assuming `DataNode` is a template, you don't have to use an ugly dummy template-parameter as in `class NullNode : public DataNode<int> ...`, and this arrangement is also a better fit for the “is-a” relationship.